# Object of class Restaurant could not be converted to string in on line 83

Tags: php, sql, oop

hello Im a beginner in PHP and i have a problem I can't seem to solve

this is the problem in my Restaurant class

```
public function getAll()
{
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "phprestaurant");
    // Line 83 follows:
    $sql = "select * from restaurants where user_id =" . $conn->$this->m_iRestoID . ""; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

and here I make the for each to loop out my results

```
$r = new Restaurant();
$all = $r->getAll();


<?php foreach($all as $a) { ?>
  <li><a href="#"> <?= $a['Naam']?> </a ></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$conn->$this` doesn't look right to me...

Comment: `$conn->$this->m_iRestoID` is _very suspect_.  Is that really your code?  If it doesn't cause a syntax error, it is attempting a dynamic property name to `$conn`.

Comment: I've used it before in ans INSERT statement and it works

Answer (score 0):

in this code

```
 $sql = "select * from restaurants where user_id =" . $conn->$this->m_iRestoID . "";
```

$this will refer to the class the whole thing is in. I would say that this causes your error, as php expects the name of a member of $conn there ....

Comment: I deleted the $conn and it's fixes but i get a new error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 32 http://puu.sh/8uYnq.png

Comment: that probably means you didn't get any results back, and you can't `foreach` on `false`